# kate: get back old document switcher (as in Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: plugins, kate

In Ubuntu 14.04 `kate` (version 3.13.3) had such a nice "quick document switcher": When hitting control+tab, it showed a list of files and by typing a few letters the list was reduced to the ones matching this expression and you could select the one you wanted. Very powerful.

This was great especially when you have many documents open (usually I have open something like 50 documents), in which case you don't want to scroll through the full list (it's much faster to type the first few letters).

Unfortunately, in Ubuntu 16.04 this plugin has been replaced by a close-to-useless switcher (no more typing -- actually it doesn't bring any benefit). Is there any way to get the old one back?

Answer (score 0):

After writing to the developer's mailing, I learned that this feature is still there but no longer implemented as a plugin.

It is called `Quick Open` and available from the `View` menu. It is assigned the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> by default.